# Why isn't Yii framework outputting a Bootstrap page?

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, yii

I downloaded and installed Yii, the test drive was working great at first.

Then I went and installed/configured yii-booster, the "testdrive" outputs a completely blank page.

Here's what my "main.php" in the configs folder looks like:

```
<?php

// uncomment the following to define a path alias
// Yii::setPathOfAlias('local','path/to/local-folder');

// This is the main Web application configuration. Any writable
// CWebApplication properties can be configured here.
return array(

'basePath'=>dirname(__FILE__).DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'..',
'name'=>'My Web Application',

// preloading 'log' component
'preload'=>array(
'log',
'bootstrap',
),

// autoloading model and component classes
'import'=>array(
    'application.models.*',
    'application.components.*',
),

'modules'=>array(
    // uncomment the following to enable the Gii tool

    'gii'=>array(
        'class'=>'system.gii.GiiModule',
        'password'=>'root',
        // If removed, Gii defaults to localhost only. Edit carefully to taste.
        'ipFilters'=>array('127.0.0.1','::1'),
        'generatorPaths' => array(
            'bootstrap.gii'
        ),
    ),
),

// application components
'components'=>array(
    'user'=>array(
        // enable cookie-based authentication
        'allowAutoLogin'=>true,
    ),

        'bootstrap' => array(
            'class' => 'ext.bootstrap.components.Bootstrap',
            'responsiveCss' => true,
        )
    ),
    // uncomment the following to enable URLs in path-format
    /*
    'urlManager'=>array(
        'urlFormat'=>'path',
        'rules'=>array(
            '<controller:\w+>/<id:\d+>'=>'<controller>/view',
            '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<id:\d+>'=>'<controller>/<action>',
            '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>'=>'<controller>/<action>',
        ),
    ),
    */
    'db'=>array(
        'connectionString' => 'sqlite:'.dirname(__FILE__).'/../data/testdrive.db',
    ),
    // uncomment the following to use a MySQL database
    /*
    'db'=>array(
        'connectionString' => 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=testdrive',
        'emulatePrepare' => true,
        'username' => 'root',
        'password' => '',
        'charset' => 'utf8',
    ),
    */
    'errorHandler'=>array(
        // use 'site/error' action to display errors
        'errorAction'=>'site/error',
    ),
    'log'=>array(
        'class'=>'CLogRouter',
        'routes'=>array(
            array(
                'class'=>'CFileLogRoute',
                'levels'=>'error, warning',
            ),
            // uncomment the following to show log messages on web pages
            /*
            array(
                'class'=>'CWebLogRoute',
            ),
            */
        ),
    ),
),

// application-level parameters that can be accessed
// using Yii::app()->params['paramName']
'params'=>array(
    // this is used in contact page
    'adminEmail'=>'webmaster@example.com',
),
);
```

I had followed the folder hierarchy and instructions from the Yii-booster site. 
Not sure what is causing this blank page when I run a "testdrive" web app.

Comment: wasn't your codeigniter page returning blank too?

Comment: @itachi: My guess is he gave up on CI and is trying Yii now.

Comment: you two are correct, please do excuse me from my previous questions. I gave up on CI and decided to finally go with Yii

Comment: check the source, check the status in network tab. see if it is returning any error.

Comment: @itachi, thank you for the humbling experience. I am a bit of a noob (as I have proven), but I don't know what you mean by checking the source and status in the network tab.

Comment: press ctrl+u on firefox. use firebug addon for forefox. else in chrome, find the developer tools from the menu, click it and there will be network tab in both the cases. see what status it returns.

Comment: @itachi It's completely blank, the tabs show nothing.

Comment: Check if you've enabled error reporting in PHP and `YII_DEBUG` is set to `true`.

Comment: @schmunk, how or where can I change that setting to true?

Comment: Usually it's in `index.php`.